# Google App Engine NDB ancestor query not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
query = Comment.query(ancestor = userKey, ndb.OR(Comment.modifiedDate > lastSyncDate, Comment.activityDate > lastSyncDate))
```

The 1 equal sign (=) is how the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor) said we should have it, but my app doesn't run when I have just 1 equal sign (build error). If I use two equal sign, like `ancestor == userKey`, then the app runs, but I get a `NameError: global name 'ancestor' is not defined`. What gives?

I also tried another variant of this query, but the same exact problem occurs:

```
query = Comment.query(ndb.AND(ancestor == userKey, ndb.OR(Comment.modifiedDate > lastSyncDate, Comment.activityDate > lastSyncDate)))
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters well I'm using textmate, and I hit cmd+r to run, and it just shows an error with the arrow pointing at the first > sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the `ancestor` keyword *after* the method positional parameters:

```
query = Comment.query(
    ndb.OR(Comment.modifiedDate > lastSyncDate, Comment.activityDate > lastSyncDate),
    ancestor=userKey)
```

Alternatively, use the `filters` keyword explicitly, or use the `.filter()` method:

```
query = Comment.query(
    ancestor=userKey,
    filters=ndb.OR(Comment.modifiedDate > lastSyncDate, Comment.activityDate > lastSyncDate))
```

or

```
query = Comment.query(ancestor=userKey).filter(ndb.OR(Comment.modifiedDate > lastSyncDate, Comment.activityDate > lastSyncDate))
```

Comment: Ya looks like putting ancestor after did the trick..good catch

Comment: Ah yes, I must provide the answerers with their daily dose of points lest they feen or go through withdrawal ;)

Comment: @mohabitar: Head to head with Jon Skeet (futile, I know)... Thanks!