# Doing an ancestor query with nested AND/OR in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm using Google App Engine NDB, and trying to do the following query:

```
query = Club.query(ndb.OR(
ndb.AND(Club.memberIds == userId, Club.modifiedDate > date), 
ndb.AND(Club.activityDate > date, ancestor = userKey)
))
```

However, I get a run time error:

```
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ancestor'
```

It has something to do with the position of ancestor. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267140/458960) was able to point out the solution in one case, but that solution would not apply here, since the ancestor is in the actual AND clause.

1. How can I reformat this query to work?
2. Is this query a bad idea? Is it too complex? Will it cost me any additional reads than usual due to its complexity?

Comment: I suspect the ancestor has to be a parameter of query() rather than AND()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the ancestor as part of a filter; it must be a keyword parameter directly on the query() call.  Currently, OR queries are turned into multiple queries anyway, so the only benefit the OR() method gives you is easier combining of the results.  But for that to work you have to order by key anyway, and it's trivial to write a little merge function that merges two sets of query results ordered by key.  (It's also possible to have that done by invoking ndb.query._MultiQuery() but the latter is not a documented API and is rather iffy to get right, so it's probably better to do this yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to rewrite the query to use GQL?

**EDIT**

To shoot down my own suggestion. It is not possible to rewrite your query to use GQL. GQL does not support `OR`.

See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference

**SUGGESTION**
You can do the query you want if you also modify the ancestor object as a Model attribute. E.g.

```
class Club(ndb.Model):
    parent = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

Comment: But I only want to AND it to the second part of the query, not the first part. So I want `OR(query1WITHOUTancestor, query2WITHancestor)`

Comment: Yeah, I have changed my suggestion.

Comment: It is not clear to me that you need an ancestor at all. Ancestor's are usually used to suggest locality of the data (i.e. suggesting to appengine to store that date on the same disk). This is necessary to perform locking on the data for transactional processing. Is this what you require?

Comment: Ya that would probably work. I am trying to be stingy with the number of queries I perform, so instead of running 2 queries, I thought I might combine them into one with ANDS and ORS. But apparently, the query I have above runs two queries anyway right?

Comment: I am not sure. However, in general it is better to run a query than to fetch the data and then perform the filtering yourself.